# Replicate same data.frame n times and save them into a list

Tags: r, list, dataframe, replicate

I just need to replicate my data.frame n times (e.g. 100) and save all the outputs into a list.

It should be quite easy and straightforward but I could not find any solution yet.

Fake data.frame:

```
df = read.table(text = 'a b
1 2
5 6
4 4
11 78
23 99', header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Replicate? Isn't that just the same output, over and over?

Comment: yes, exactly.....I need it because I want to manipulate them eventually in n different ways

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With `lapply`:

```
df_list <- lapply(1:100, function(x) df)
```

Comment: This solved a similar problem for me as well. I am curious about the syntax. Why does this result in basic replication?  
Is the function(x) basically a non-function, so you are repeating "df" 1:100 times but without doing anything to it?

Answer (score 9):

We can use `replicate`

```
n <- 100
lst <- replicate(n, df, simplify = FALSE)
```

Comment: If this helped, you should mark the checkbox beside it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rep` if you wrap it in `list`, as `rep` tries to return the same type of object you pass it:

```r
df_list <- rep(list(df), 100)

str(df_list[1:2])
#> List of 2
#>  $ :'data.frame':    5 obs. of  2 variables:
#>   ..$ a: int [1:5] 1 5 4 11 23
#>   ..$ b: int [1:5] 2 6 4 78 99
#>  $ :'data.frame':    5 obs. of  2 variables:
#>   ..$ a: int [1:5] 1 5 4 11 23
#>   ..$ b: int [1:5] 2 6 4 78 99
```